# Dynkin diagram related question

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm struggling with drawing the graph from the 8th step in page 61 of **Humphrey's book Introduction to Lie Algebra and Representation Theory.** Since they're not standard Dynkin diagrams, I can't find a way to draw it with package {dynkin-diagrams}. What are the simplest way to draw these graphs? Thanks for your help.
[image: graph]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Tex.Se. What is your actual problem? Do you already have some code you can provide. You cannot assume that everyone owns this book. What does the graph look like? We cannot give you a proper recommendation  without knowing that.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! I recommend adding the figure and a minimal working example.

Comment: @Roland  Sorry! I have added the graph right now.

Comment: @BlackMild Sorry! I've added the graph.

Comment: I decided not to include these diagrams in the dynkin-diagrams package, because I wanted it to be limited for the sake of error checking and because general diagrams should probably be done in a general package. If someone thinks I should put these in, I suppose I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly this requires digging into the hidden features in the undocumented next layer of the [dynkin-diagrams](https://ctan.org/pkg/dynkin-diagrams) package.
[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extraNode}[6]%
{%
\dynkinPlaceRootRelativeTo{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
\dynkinDefiniteSingleEdge{#1}{#2}
\dynkinRootMark{o}{#1}
\advance\dynkin@nodes by 1
\dynkinLabelRoot{#1}{#6} 
}%
\newcommand{\extraDotNode}[6]%
{%
\dynkinPlaceRootRelativeTo{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
\dynkinIndefiniteSingleEdge{#1}{#2}
\dynkinRootMark{o}{#1}
\advance\dynkin@nodes by 1
\dynkinLabelRoot{#1}{#6} 
}%
\makeatother
\tikzset{/Dynkin diagram,mark=o,edge length=.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\dynkin A{}
\\
\begin{dynkinDiagram}A{ooo.o}
\dynkinLabelRoot{1}{\varepsilon_1}
\dynkinLabelRoot{2}{\varepsilon_2}
\dynkinLabelRoot{3}{\varepsilon_3}
\dynkinLabelRoot{4}{\varepsilon_p}
\dynkin[at=(root 4),arrows=false]B2
\dynkin[at=(root 2),labels={\eta_q,\eta_{q-1},\eta_2,\eta_1}]A{oo.oo}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\\
\dynkin[arrows=false] G{2}
\\
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[labels={\varepsilon_{p-1},\psi,\zeta_{r-1},\eta_{q-1}},mark=o,edge length=.75cm]D4
\extraDotNode{5}{3}{northeast}{right}{left}{\zeta_2}
\extraDotNode{6}{4}{southeast}{right}{left}{\eta_2}
\extraDotNode{7}{1}{west}{below}{above}{\varepsilon_2}
\extraNode{8}{5}{northeast}{right}{left}{\zeta_1}
\extraNode{9}{6}{southeast}{right}{left}{\eta_1}
\extraNode{10}{7}{west}{below}{above}{\varepsilon_1}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The angle of the last one is chosen to ensure the symmetry of rotation by a third of a revolution; it is a little tall.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[edot/.style={fill=white,circle,draw,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0,outer sep=0},xscale=1.5]  

% first line
\path 
(0,0) node{$\cdots$}
(.5,0) node[edot] (R1) {}
(1.5,0) node[edot] (R2) {}
(-.5,0) node[edot] (L1) {}
(-1.5,0) node[edot] (L2) {}
;       
\draw (L1)--(L2) (R1)--(R2);

% second line
\path 
(2,-1) node{$\cdots$}
(.5,-1) node[edot] (1R1) {} node[below=1mm]{$\eta_q$}
(1.5,-1) node[edot] (1R2) {} node[below=1mm]{$\eta_{q-1}$}
(2.5,-1) node[edot] (1R3) {} node[below=1mm]{$\eta_2$}
(3.5,-1) node[edot] (1R4) {} node[below=1mm]{$\eta_1$}
(-2,-1) node{$\cdots$}
(-.5,-1) node[edot] (1L1) {} node[below=1mm]{$\epsilon_q$}
(-1.5,-1) node[edot] (1L2) {} node[below=1mm]{$\epsilon_{q-1}$}
(-2.5,-1) node[edot] (1L3) {} node[below=1mm]{$\epsilon_2$}
(-3.5,-1) node[edot] (1L4) {} node[below=1mm]{$\epsilon_1$}
;       
\draw 
(1L1)--(1L2) (1L3)--(1L4) (1R1)--(1R2) (1R3)--(1R4)
(1L1.90)--(1R1.90) (1L1.-90)--(1R1.-90);

% third line
\path 
(.5,-2) node[edot] (2R1) {}
(-.5,-2) node[edot] (2L1) {}
;
\draw (2L1)--(2R1) (2L1.90)--(2R1.90) (2L1.-90)--(2R1.-90); 

% fourth line
\def\t{20}
\path 
(0,-4) node[edot] (3) {} node[above=1mm] {$\Psi$}
++(\t:1) node[edot] (3R1a) {} node[above=1mm]{$\zeta_{r-1}$}
++(\t:.5) node[rotate=\t]{$\cdots$}
++(\t:.5) node[edot] (3R2a) {} node[above=1mm]{$\zeta_2$}
++(\t:1) node[edot] (3R3a) {} node[above=1mm]{$\zeta_1$}
(0,-4)
++(-\t:1) node[edot] (3R1b) {} node[below=1mm]{$\eta_{q-1}$}
++(-\t:.5) node[rotate=-\t]{$\cdots$}
++(-\t:.5) node[edot] (3R2b) {} node[below=1mm]{$\eta_2$}
++(-\t:1) node[edot] (3R3b) {} node[below=1mm]{$\eta_1$}
(-1,-4) node[edot] (3L1) {} node[below=1mm]{$\epsilon_{p-1}$}
(-1.5,-4) node {$\cdots$}
(-2,-4) node[edot] (3L2) {} node[below=1mm]{$\epsilon_2$}
(-3,-4) node[edot] (3L3) {} node[below=1mm]{$\epsilon_1$}
;
\draw (3)--(3R1a) (3R2a)--(3R3a) (3)--(3R1b) (3R2b)--(3R3b)
(3)--(3L1) (3L2)--(3L3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the first and the third line can be drawn by using package {dynkin-diagrams}. The first is $\dynkin A{}$, and the third one is $\dykin G2$

Comment: @nielswen `dynkin-diagrams` gives a quick way. Plain TikZ is using when more controls (color, size of dots, ...) are needed, or some non-standard Dynkin figures.

Answer (score 0):

This provides you all you will need for drawing the graph to start:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \node[circle,draw,label={[yshift=-1cm]t1}] at (0,0) (t1) {};    
        \node[circle,draw,label={[yshift=-1cm]t2}] at (2,0) (t2) {};    
        \node[circle,draw,label={[yshift=-1cm]t3}] at (4,0) (t3) {};
        \node[circle,draw,label={[yshift=-1.1cm]tp}] at (6,0) (tp) {};
        \node[circle,draw,label={[yshift=-1.1cm]$n_{q}$}] at (8,0) (nq) {};
        \node[circle,draw,label={[yshift=-1.1cm]$n_{q-1}$}] at (10,0) (nq1) {};
        \node[circle,draw,label={[yshift=-1.1cm]$n_{2}$}] at (12,0) (n2) {};
        \node[circle,draw,label={[yshift=-1.1cm]$n_{3}$}] at (14,0) (n3) {};
        
        
        \draw [-] (t1) edge (t2) (t2) edge (t3) (t3) edge[line width=2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 5,shorten <=3] (tp) (tp) edge[double,double distance=4pt] (nq) (nq) edge (nq1) (nq1) edge[line width=2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 5,shorten <=3] (n2) (n2) edge (n3); 
        
        \node[circle,draw,above=of t3]  (a) {}; 
        \node[circle,draw,above=of tp]  (b) {}; 
        \node[circle,draw,above=of nq]  (c) {}; 
        \node[circle,draw,above=of nq1]  (d) {};    
        \draw [-] (a) edge (b) (b) edge[line width=2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 5,shorten <=3] (c) (c) edge (d);

    \end{tikzpicture}

    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]